# how to set winform checkboxlist items to be semi-checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I don't know if this is possible at all, but if someone knows how to achive this it will be geat.
I have a check-box-list in winform and I need some check-boxes to be semi-checked (e.g. the check-box is not checked and not not checked). Is it even possible to do this in winforms check-box-list ? If not, is it possible to achive this with a regular check-box and not a check-box-list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be achieved on the CheckListBox but you have to set the indeterminate state yourself, from MSDN:

> The CheckedListBox object supports three states through the CheckState enumeration: Checked, Indeterminate, and Unchecked. You must set the state of Indeterminate in the code because the user interface for a CheckedListBox does not provide a mechanism to do so.

There is also a code example:

```
  // Adds the string if the text box has data in it. 
  private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     if(textBox1.Text != "")
     {
        if(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(textBox1.Text)== false)
           checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text,CheckState.Checked);  // here you can set CheckState.Indeterminate!
        textBox1.Text = "";
     }
  }
```

for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The checkboxlist has a DataSource.
I tried it like this `chkListPermissionGroups.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);` but all it does is showing the checkbox in disabled...

Comment: @LiranFridman the CheckedState.Indeterminate is a checked CheckBox but with a gray background color to show its indeterminate state, see MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemcheckstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But in a regular checkbox it shows otherwise...
Even so, when I click on the checkbox it doesn't change to three states, only between checked and unchecked

Comment: @LiranFridman If you refer to the style where the indeterminate state is a square (instead of a check) within the square, that dependes on which control you are using. Maybe they are differently implemented or it depends on the Windows UI theme.

Comment: But when I click on the checkbox it doesn't toggle 3 states. It only toggles 2: checked and unchecked

Comment: @LiranFridman that is exactly what is written above _You must set the state of Indeterminate in the code because the user interface for a CheckedListBox does not provide a mechanism to do so._ To me this is very clear. So I guess you will end up listening to the CheckedChanged event and setting the state yourself to indeterminate if it was e.g. check before.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = checkedListBox1.Items.Add("test");
    checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(index, CheckState.Indeterminate);
}
```

[image: Indeterminate]

Setting the indeterminate state when clicking it:

```
void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CurrentValue)
    {
        case CheckState.Checked:
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
            break;

        case CheckState.Indeterminate:
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
            break;

        case CheckState.Unchecked:
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the checkbox is not showed as semi-checked. It only shows as checked in gray color like disabled

Comment: Provided a picture. Does it look anything like this? If you want, you can provide your own state images, if the standard ones is not satisfying.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But when I click on the checkbox it doesn't toggle 3 states. It only toggles 2: checked and unchecked.

Comment: Provided code to set indeterminate state when clicking an item.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a checkbox. Set the [`ThreeState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true:

```
checkBox1.ThreeState = true;
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the CheckBox will allow three
>   check states rather than two.

`CheckState` can be:

```
CheckState.Checked 
CheckState.Indeterminate
CheckState.Unchecked
```

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CheckState state = checkBox1.CheckState;

        switch (state)
        {
        case CheckState.Checked:
        case CheckState.Indeterminate:
        case CheckState.Unchecked:
            {
            MessageBox.Show(state.ToString());
            break;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: -> "If not, is it possible to achive this with a regular check-box and not a check-box-list ?"

Comment: I saw it, thanks. Can you please tell me how do I set the semi-checked state ?